# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException within Transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

Currently using slightly older Hibernate (3.3.2.GA) - and getting org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException within Transaction boundaries. I confirmed that the calling method is marked `@Transactional`, plus stack trace at the time of exception is showing it too:
`org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)`

Still, an attempt to iterate over `@CollectionOfElements` promptly throws the LazyInitializationException with " no session or session was closed ".

While debugging it, I see that Hibernate proxy on the relevant collection has a session of null virtually as soon as it is loaded by Hibernate. Is that something to worry about? How can I track this down and resolve it - in other words, while debugging, what's the best way to track down what is happening to the session?

Obviously I understand that changing the collection to Eager fetching will resolve the issue, but I rather figure out why Lazy Load is not working since this (potentially) large collection is not needed in most scenarios.

Thank You!

Comment: If you are trying to iterate over your Collection but are already out of the scope of the transaction in which you obtained your Entity, if the proxy was not initialized previously, you will get that results. It is only normal, correct? There are two ways to approach this issue: one is setting the fetching to Eager (not recommended since in your own words it's 'not needed in most scenarios'). The second option is, when this Collection is needed, to initialize it in the transaction it was obtained and then use it.  Advice to you: avoid crossing transactional boundaries as much as you can.

Comment: Again - the missing link in my brain is "within the same transaction" - I really believe I still am as I am seeing it in the call-stack also. Perhaps I'll try to debug transaction aspect directly to see if my assumption is wrong there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adir1 I had exactly the same problem. In my case the issue was caused by the fact that the instance which contained the lazy-loaded collection had been manually evicted before (all within transaction boundaries).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when you return from the method fetching the entity and start iterating through it you're already at different transactional contexts, thus leading to the lazy initialization problem; if you're using a DAO try setting both of these methods to the same transaction (i.e setting them as REQUIRED).

I might be totally mistaken though. I've just tested this with EJB3 + JPA and got the lazy initialization problems you described when the method fetching the entity was at a different transactional context.

EDIT: Like baba said in his comment, a better solution would be either eager fetching through HQL / Criteria (fetch join clause in HQL) or, less preferably, using Hibernate.initialize before returning it.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts - I was really hoping for someone with intimate familiarity with that aspect of Hibernate. Since it clearly appears that I am within the same transaction context when I access the lazy fields, it's unclear to me why it thinks session is closed.

Comment: Well, not sure if it helps, but I meant you need to check if you're really in the same transaction, especially if the entity was returned from another component (i.e a DAO); the fact that the calling method is @Transactional might not mean that every subsequent call from another method in another class is at the same transactional context - thus leading to the lazy initialization problem.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the age of this question, for posterity:

The same problem happened for me because I kept entities cached in memory. The exception was thrown as soon as accessing those entities in a later transaction - different from the one during which the entities were first collected. Hence the lost session problem.

Solved by setting up proper 2nd level caching.